# logstash filter: get all array elements as new event

Tags: ruby, xml, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to get array elements after xml parser as following:

```
filter {
  xml {
      source => "message"
      target => "xmldata"
      store_xml => "false"
      xpath => ["/OMA/ESMLog/LogEntry/Index/text()","index"]
      xpath => ["/OMA/ESMLog/LogEntry/Status/text()","status"]
      xpath => ["/OMA/ESMLog/LogEntry/TimeStampRaw/text()","timestampraw"]
      xpath => ["/OMA/ESMLog/LogEntry/Description/text()","description"]
  }
        mutate { 
            remove_field => [ "message", "inxml", "xmldata" ] 
        }

    mutate {
    replace => {
            "index" => "%{[index][0]}"
        "status" => "%{[status][0]}"
            "timestampraw" => "%{[timestampraw][0]}"
            "description" => "%{[description][0]}"

     }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestampraw", "UNIX" ]
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm able to get every first element from the arrays, but how can I get all elements from the arrays as a new event?
So, I want to see every 'LogEntry' element as a new event from the XML.
Here some example xml(raw xml from omsa):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OMA>
<ESMLog>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>0</Index>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Tue Nov  3 07:22:57 2015</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1446535377</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>The system board Mem2 temperature is within range.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>1</Index>
        <Status>3</Status>
        <TimeStamp>System Boot</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1446535378</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>The system board Mem2 temperature is less than the lower warning threshold.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>2</Index>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Mon Nov  2 14:17:09 2015</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1446473829</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Drive 0 is installed in disk drive bay 1.</Description>
        </LogEntry>
        <LogEntry>
        <Index>3</Index>
        <Status>4</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Mon Nov  2 14:17:04 2015</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1446473824</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Drive 0 is removed from disk drive bay 1.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>4</Index>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Mon Nov  2 14:15:54 2015</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1446473754</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Drive 0 is installed in disk drive bay 1.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>5</Index>
        <Status>4</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Mon Nov  2 13:58:54 2015</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1446472734</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Drive 0 is removed from disk drive bay 1.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>6</Index>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Fri Feb  5 11:07:27 2010</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1265368047</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Drive 0 is installed in disk drive bay 1.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>7</Index>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Fri Feb  5 11:07:08 2010</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1265368028</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Drive 0 in disk drive bay 1 is operating normally.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>8</Index>
        <Status>4</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Fri Feb  5 11:07:07 2010</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1265368027</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Drive 0 is removed from disk drive bay 1.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>9</Index>
        <Status>4</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Fri Jan 29 09:33:27 2010</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1264757607</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Fault detected on drive 0 in disk drive bay 1.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
        <Index>10</Index>
        <Status>2</Status>
        <TimeStamp>Mon Feb 25 16:14:15 2008</TimeStamp>
        <TimeStampRaw>1203956055</TimeStampRaw>
        <Description>Log cleared.</Description>
    </LogEntry>
    <NumRecords>11</NumRecords>
</ESMLog>
<ObjStatus>2</ObjStatus>
<SMStatus>0</SMStatus>
</OMA>
```

**Here is the solution I made, by Jettro's example:**

```
filter {
        xml {
                source => "message"
                target => "xmldata"
                store_xml => "false"
                xpath => ["/OMA/ESMLog//LogEntry","logentry"]
        }

        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "message", "inxml", "xmldata" ]
        }

        split {
                field => "[logentry]"
        }

        xml {
                source => "logentry"
                store_xml => "false"
                xpath => ["/LogEntry/Index/text()","index"]
                xpath => ["/LogEntry/Status/text()","status"]
                xpath => ["/LogEntry/TimeStampRaw/text()","timestampraw"]
                xpath => ["/LogEntry/Description/text()","description"]
        }
        mutate {
                replace => {
                "index" => "%{[index][0]}"
                "status" => "%{[status][0]}"
                "timestampraw" => "%{[timestampraw][0]}"
                "description" => "%{[description][0]}"

                }
        }
   date {
            match => [ "timestampraw", "UNIX" ]
    }
            mutate {
        remove_field => [ "logentry" , "timestampraw" ]
    }
}
```

It seems after the split start to create a "loop" and process all the array from the deeper sections.
thanks

Comment: Did you forget to ad your output ? I dont' see any in your post

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I didn't added any, because output was fine with the code. I was looking solution to develop the filter instead of fix it. 
Jettro's answer helped a lot and I was able to made the necessary changes. I updated the post with the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example is a bit verbose to try I made an easier xml, but you should be able to get out of it what you need. The trick is to use the split filter. Below the config I used and the output.

```
# <result><logline><description>item 1</description></logline><logline><description>item 2</description></logline></result>
input {
    stdin{}
}
filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        store_xml => "false"
        xpath => ["/result/logline","loglines"]
        remove_field => [ "message", "host" ] 
    }
    split {
        field => "loglines"
    }
    xml {
        source => "loglines"
        store_xml => "false"
        xpath => ["/logline/description/text()","description"]
        remove_field => [ "loglines" ] 
    }    
}
output {
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And the output then becomes:

```
{
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2016-06-07T09:40:35.420Z",
           "host" => "Jettros-MBP.fritz.box",
    "description" => [
        [0] "item 1"
    ]
}
{
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2016-06-07T09:40:35.420Z",
           "host" => "Jettros-MBP.fritz.box",
    "description" => [
        [0] "item 2"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, there are now two events.

Comment: Thank you Jettro. Your example made me understand the split, then I was able to fix my filter.